# Store event with fullcalendar and Laravel without maddhatter method

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, fullcalendar

I am trying to use the full calendar and the larval to create an event management system.
I am facing one the problem which are i dont know how to add the data into the database. Create a database is easier, but how to connect it and add, delete, edit is a little bit harder for me. This is my code for the calendar view, it can let me click and add event, and drag to other timeline, but it doesnt connect to the database.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Check calender div is exist or not.
        // In case of guest user it will not present
        if($("#calendar").length ){
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                theme: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                selectable:true,
                selectHelper:true,
                select: function(start, end){
                    var title = prompt('Event Title :');
                    var eventData;
                    if(title){
                        eventData = {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end:end
                        };
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',eventData,true);
                    }
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                },
                editable:true,
                eventLimit:true
            });
        }

    });
</script>
```

My question is, if i want to connect with the database. How to add into the laravel 5.2 ? The events can added without refresh the page?
And how to manage to add the event into my database with the function can drag?
Thanks for any suggestions and helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several stops to be done:

1. Load existing events into calendar when the page is opened.

Use whatever method you prefer (jQuery AJAX, JavaScript native calls, reactive JS frameworks, etc) to load the data from your server and then pass it to Full Calendar like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', events[i], true);
}
```

If you don't like AJAX calls, you could fetch existing events in Laravel and display them in the Blade template as an array. But you will need AJAX anyway to create/modify events so it's probably better to use the same logic.

2. Process calendar updates

Then, when user drags/adds another event onto the calendar, Full Calendar will call eventDrop method, so define it inside your fullCalendar initialisation block:

```
eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    // This is just an example of a reverse function
    if (event.start.unix() < (Date.now() / 1000)) {
        revertFunc();
    } else {
        // Some method here that will make another AJAX call to your server and save the new event in the database
        self.addEvent(event);
    }
},
```

You will need a Laravel controller to deal with these AJAX calls and I would recommend to create a resource controller – it fits here perfectly. You will use index() method in the beginning to display all existing events and you will use update(), destroy() and so on to modify existing events.

Comment: How about the database connection with the laravel?

Comment: Laravel has database connection working out of the box – simply adjust your config/databases.php values. Then, creating a model (in Laravel they are called Eloquent) is trivial, and it will fetch data from your database automatically. I just thought if I describe all steps in detail – the answer will be several pages long! Also, it will go beyond the original question topic

Comment: OK， because i quite no famillar with the laravel. So i hope can do it by myself, then it will make me more clear. So that means, i need to migrate another database first, and then create a Eloquent like the User.php in the Laravel? @DenisMysenko

Comment: yes exactly! you are going to have an 'event' model, you can create it like: php artisan make:model -m Event. then adjust your database columns in the corresponding file in migrations folder. you will find it quite easy, that's why Laravel is so popular!

Comment: Yeah, i know the laravel is the top 1 framework. Just i need some time to understand how this works. I try it first, then later tell you again.

Comment: i have created the database table , but still not understand how to link with the cal.blade.php, so i can store the event into my database. @DenisMysenko

Answer (score 1):

You could use the event that default of the fullcalendar. It will pass the json form data to the calendar view. Basically it will need :`[{'id':'1','title':'Valentine's day','start':'01-10-2016','end':'01-11-2016'}]`

If you can get the json form like that, then pass to the event there, then can success view the data inside the calendar view. Hope this help.